# enable show-paren-mode in init.el

Tags: init-file, balanced-parentheses

I would like to enable `show-paren-mode` in my configuration file `init.el`, which is very convenient for debugging.
As it is a minor mode as I've understood, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

I think `(show-paren-mode 1)` should do the job.

You can also try `highlight-parentheses-mode` if you want to highlight the cursor's current scope.

This is my config:

`(use-package highlight-parentheses
   :ensure t
   :pin melpa
   :config 
   (setq hl-paren-background-colors '("orangered4"))
   (setq hl-paren-colors '("black")))`

Comment: I love `use-package` but I've never used `:pin melpa` before. Just curious, what does it do ?

Comment: it determines the repository you want to use

Comment: isn't that redundant most of the times? I get 90% of the packages from melpa

Comment: yes it is...in most cases

Comment: You might find `:pin` useful depending on the sort priority of your package repos. For example, you might want to pick up packages from melpa-stable where possible, so you give that higher priority. Then you might want to pin a specific package to melpa because you always want the latest version.